# SPNEGO and Kerberos ticket cache

Tags: java, linux, firefox, chromium, spnego

I'm using Linux, Play-Scala web servers, Java, and Firefox to play around with Kerberos.

Here's my question:  What would be the best way to create a ticket cache if the user's ticket is empty?  Add statements to the login shell script to call "kinit {user}"?  Or have a form login and let the web server call kinit for the user?  Is there a way to force Firefox to login prompt the user so that Firefox will create the ticket cache from the users supplied credentials, just as like I tell the web browser to start SPNEGO when the server responds with **WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate**?

Firefox-Linux is reading the ticket cache.  I'm an not having luck with Chromium.  I used **chromium --auth-server-whitelist="localhost"**.  Is there any other configuration settings to get Chromium to read the ticket cache?

Comment: Java apps can _(a)_ read the TGT from the Kerberos cache -- defined via `KRB5CCNAME` env variable or via `/etc/krb5.conf` entry or via system-specific hardcoded default -- or _(b)_ create a TGT on-the-fly -- by using a keytab file and/or by prompting _(if the prompt feature is unlocked in the `security` params)_ -- and keep it private in memory, according to the current JAAS configuration. And they will always manage service tickets on-the-fly. But they will never write anything to the cache.

Comment: For **services** you should create / renew / re-create the TGT in the cache periodically, with `kinit` and optionally `kinit -R`, triggered either by CRON or by your Java service. For **users**, well, do they connect from a Linux box using SSSD to bind user accounts to an external LDAP+Kerberos system, that would permit SSO? Otherwise the standard approach is to use LDAP auth to the web server (SSL + form or SSL + BASIC auth) and allow the server to "impersonate" users -- cf. Apache Knox for example.

Comment: BTW a **service** would probably don't need the cache at all; keeping the Kerberos tickets private and in-memory is better in terms of security and robustness _(cf. possible race conditions while the renewal process is rewriting the cache)_